# Generate doc file from tex file

Tags: conversion, msword

I want to write my thesis in latex but I need to include doc and pdf file on a CD. Is it possible to generate doc file from latex?

Comment: Give [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) a quick look.  I think it only handles new Word (docx) rather than old (doc), but LibreOffice can be [used headless](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14667/converting-document-in-headless-mode-in-linux/).

Comment: @JohnC it work. It don't preserve the font (all is in arial) but you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) will convert most major formats to both PDF and old Microsoft Word (doc).  LibreOffice can then be [used headless](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14667/converting-document-in-headless-mode-in-linux/).

For the font issue, there is the `--reference-docx=FILE` option.

> Use the specified file as a style reference in producing a docx file. For best results, *the reference docx should be a modified version of a docx file produced using pandoc*. The contents of the reference docx are ignored, but its stylesheets are used in the new docx.

Emphasis added.